# Dúvida em método computado Vue utilizando Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Tenho o seguinte código abaixo utilizando **Vue.js** e **Vuex**. Este código incrementa e decrementa valor como um contador. Gostaria de saber ao que se refere o método **`count`** dentro de **computed** na instância Vue. Sei que ele retorna o estado da váriavel **count** do **`state`**. Mas pq o nome do método tem que ser o nome da variável? Se eu troco o nome do método o código não funciona.

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    count: 0
  },
  mutations: {
    incrementa: state => state.count++,
    decrementa: state => state.count--
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  computed: {
    count() {                   // Dúvida -> ao que se refere count
      return store.state.count
    }
  },
  methods: {
    incrementa() {
      store.commit('incrementa')
    },
    decrementa() {
      store.commit('decrementa')
    }
  }
})
```

```css
span{padding: 0 15px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.0.1/dist/vuex.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>
    <button @click="incrementa">+</button>
    <span>{{ count }}</span>
    <button @click="decrementa">-</button>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A propriedade `computed` do objeto Vue é onde se declara suas [Computed Properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html).

Dá para se pensar em Computed Properties como propriedades onde se definem apenas os getters (e opcionalmente, setters) para algo.
Não há um valor registrado na propriedade, e sim uma função getter que pode ou não busca o valor desejado em outros lugares. Uma das vantagens de usar Computed Properties no Vue.JS é que o Vue faz cache do resultado do getter, e invalida a cache caso as dependências do getter sejam alteradas.

Exemplo básico usando computed property para calcular o nome completo:

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      nome: '',
      sobrenome: ''
    },
    computed: {
      nome_completo: function () {
        // concatena e elimina espaços em excesso
        return `${this.nome } ${this.sobrenome}`.replace(/\s+/g, ' ')
      }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input v-model="nome">
  <input v-model="sobrenome">
  <div>{{ nome_completo }}</div>
</div>
```

Agora, respondendo o porquê teu código dá erro ao alterar o nome da computed property:

O `state` `count` é uma coisa, o `computed property` `count` é outra.

O `state` `count` só é referenciado dentro da função `contador()` na linha

```
return store.state.count
```

O `computed property` `count` está sendo referenciado no template, na linha

```
<span>{{ count }}</span>
```

Para acessar a `computed property` é necessário acessá-lo através do objeto Vue. Exemplo:

```
this.count  // Acessa a computed property
```

Para acessar o `state` `count` é necessário acessá-lo através do Vuex. No seu exemplo:

```
store.state.count
```

Abaixo modifiquei apenas o nome da `computed property` no objeto Vue e no template para mostrar como funciona com nomes diferentes.

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    count: 0
  },
  mutations: {
    incrementa: state => state.count++,
    decrementa: state => state.count--
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  computed: {
    contador() {  // agora é contador
      return store.state.count
    }
  },
  methods: {
    incrementa() {
      store.commit('incrementa')
    },
    decrementa() {
      store.commit('decrementa')
    }
  }
})
```

```css
span{padding: 0 15px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.0.1"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>
    <button @click="incrementa">+</button>
    <span>{{ contador }}</span> <!-- printa a computed property -->
    <button @click="decrementa">-</button>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Certo man, entendido agora. Não sabia que o **{{ count }}** que referenciava o método `count()`. Por isso dava erro, pois só trocava o nome na computed e não na interpolação. Agora ficou claro. Obrigado!

Comment: Isso... as variáveis que tu tenta dar print no template (**{{ variavel }}**) são sempre buscadas no objeto Vue, pois o template faz parte do componente também.

Answer (score 1):

No caso, o nome do método dentro da `computed` não precisa ser o mesmo nome da variável, porém o nome do atributo que está dentro do state deve ser o mesmo nome do atributo dentro da sua `store`. Veja isto no exemplo abaixo:

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
      state: {
        count: 0
      },
      mutations: {
        incrementa: state => state.count++,
        decrementa: state => state.count--
      }
    })

    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      computed: {        
        count() {                   // Dúvida -> ao que se refere count
          return store.state.count
        },
        teste() {
          return store.state.count
        }        
      },
      methods: {
        incrementa() {
          store.commit('incrementa')
        },
        decrementa() {
          store.commit('decrementa')
        }
      }
    })
```

```css
span{padding: 0 15px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.0.1/dist/vuex.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>
    <button @click="incrementa">+</button>
    <span>{{ count }}</span>
    <span>{{ teste }}</span>    
    <button @click="decrementa">-</button>
  </p>
</div>
```

Porém, usualmente é mais utilizado em aplicações reais o [mapState](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper), onde fica menos repetitivo o uso do `store` e mais claro o que você está realmente mapeamento para suas `stores`, principalmente quando há mais de uma.

Outro ponto que deve ser observado, é que em uma aplicação real você realiza uma injeção da store dentro da própria instância do Vue usualmente falando, assim usa-se com `this.$store` e não `store` diretamente.

Comment: Tudo bem, vc criou outro método **(Teste)** dentro de computed que retorna a store com a state da variável **count** e este método faz o mesmo que o método **count**, certo. Só que a dúvida persiste, se você mudar o nome do método `count()` da erro, isto que gostaria de saber o pq? Você disse na sua resposta *"No caso, o nome do método dentro da computed não precisa ser o mesmo nome da variável"*, tenta mudar o nome de count() para ver se não dá erro.

Comment: Cara se você mudar o count() da computed, tem que mudarn o HTML para o nome que você mudou, será que você não mudou? A computed é como se fosse uma variável do data(), assim tem que mudar no HTML também, o nome do HTML e na computed devem ser exatamente os mesmos.

Comment: Exato man, era isto mesmo que não estava entendendo. Eu trocava no computed mas não no Html. Obrigado plea ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Pode pensar nesses métodos dentro de `computed` como variáveis que se auto-atualizam, ou seja no template vais ter acesso a uma "variável" com o nome desse método.

No template tens `<span>{{ count }}</span>` e esse `count` é o retorno desse `count(){` dentro do `computed`.

Portanto, vê cada propriedade/método desse computed como variáveis que estão sempre atualizadas. Essa atualização deve-se a um mecanismo interno do Vue (reactividade) e que regista quais as dependências que esse método tem. E quando uma dessas dependências for atualizada o método é corrido de novo e o valor de `count` atualizado.